# Angular 2: Cannot find a differ supporting object for *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Here is client.service.ts

```
clients: Client[];

getClientList()
   { 
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
     console.log(authToken);
     headers.append('X-auth-Token', authToken)
      return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/client/list?isClient=Y', {headers})
      .map(( data: Response) => {
      this.clients= JSON.parse(data['_body']);
      return this.clients;
    })
  }
```

I have created model for client.

HomeComponent.ts

```
onTestGet()
{

      this._httpService.getClientList()
      .subscribe(
        data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
        error => alert(error),
         () => console.log("finished")
         );
  }
```

**home.html**

```
<select class="borderdiv" #select [(ngModel)]="cuurent" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-group" *ngIf="radioValue == 'yes'">
                <option *ngFor="let client of getData">  {{client.clientName}} </option>
            </select>
```

**Response data:**

```
[{"userId":"cos.com","clientCode":"75","clientName":"Abc COMPANY, THE"},{"userId":"maintenance.com","clientCode":"51","clientName":"AINC./ ALSTYLE APPAREL"}]
```

I have searched a lot.but unable to solve the problem.please help me.

Comment: Obviously `getData` is not returning the array you show as `Response data`. Try `<div>{{getData | json}}</div>`

Comment: Please post the code for `getClientList()`

Comment: i have tried {{getData | json }},getting response in html

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Why do you `JSON.stringify()` when you want an array?

Comment: thanks a lot, i have removed JSON.stringify(), yes it is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
```

should be

```
data => this.getData = data,
```